# Building an OSC message with a for loop in C++/oscpack for lidar

Tags: c++

Ok, so I'm decent with many programming languages, C++ isn't one of them. This task would take me 5 minutes in pretty much anything else, but after many tries, I'm hoping for some guidance.

My application is reading data from an [RPLidar A3](https://www.slamtec.com/en/Lidar/A3), and packaging up the data into OSC to be forwarded to other applications that work with the data and convert it into trackable blobs as a generic tracking system for people in a space. ( [It currently looks like this](https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/567531472) )
I'm doing this via a TINY modification to [their example viewer app](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_sdk) using the [oscpack](https://github.com/MariadeAnton/oscpack) library.
The sensor returns 2 values: an angle (Float) and a distance in mm (integer)

The sdk gets all the values from a spin and then you iterate through them with a loop. I have it working fine where it sends the value pairs out as it gets them "ie  lidar1/ angle distance" out a UDP socket. It looks like this:

```
 UdpTransmitSocket transmitSocket(IpEndpointName(ADDRESS, PORT));
    char lidbuffer[OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    for (int pos = 0; pos < (int)count; ++pos) {
        scanDot dot;
        
        if (!buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2) continue;

        dot.quality = buffer[pos].quality;
        dot.angle = buffer[pos].angle_z_q14 * 90.f / 16384.f;
        dot.dist = buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2 /4.0f;
        _scan_data.push_back(dot);
       
        osc::OutboundPacketStream p(lidbuffer, OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        p << osc::BeginMessage(SENDPREFIX)
            << dot.angle << (int)dot.dist << osc::EndMessage;
        transmitSocket.Send(p.Data(), p.Size());      

    }
```

It works, but as I've move to a higher resolution sensor, I'm having issues with dropped data, so I would like to build the data into a single message or a bundle. As a reference, each revolution of the sensor is about 800 angle/distance pairs.

This is what I thought would work, based on the [oscpack example](https://github.com/MariadeAnton/oscpack/blob/master/examples/SimpleSend.cpp) It compiles, but crashes on opening:

As a big message:

```
UdpTransmitSocket transmitSocket(IpEndpointName(ADDRESS, PORT));
char lidbuffer[OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
//make a new message
osc::OutboundPacketStream p(lidbuffer, OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);
p << osc::BeginMessage(SENDPREFIX);
for (int pos = 0; pos < (int)count; ++pos) {
    scanDot dot;
    
    if (!buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2) continue;

    dot.quality = buffer[pos].quality;
    dot.angle = buffer[pos].angle_z_q14 * 90.f / 16384.f;
    dot.dist = buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2 /4.0f;
    _scan_data.push_back(dot);

    //add more data into the message
    p << dot.angle << (int)dot.dist; 
      
}
//send the message
p << osc::EndMessage;
transmitSocket.Send(p.Data(), p.Size());
```

As a bundle

```
UdpTransmitSocket transmitSocket(IpEndpointName(ADDRESS, PORT));
char lidbuffer[OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
osc::OutboundPacketStream p(lidbuffer, OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);
//make a bundle
p << osc::BeginBundleImmediate;    
for (int pos = 0; pos < (int)count; ++pos) {
    scanDot dot;
    
        if (!buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2) continue;
    
        dot.quality = buffer[pos].quality;
        dot.angle = buffer[pos].angle_z_q14 * 90.f / 16384.f;
        dot.dist = buffer[pos].dist_mm_q2 /4.0f;
        _scan_data.push_back(dot);
    
        //add a message to the bundle
        p << osc::BeginMessage(SENDPREFIX) << dot.angle << (int)dot.dist << osc::EndMessage;; 
          
    }
    //send the bundle
    p << osc::EndBundle;
    transmitSocket.Send(p.Data(), p.Size());
```

Both compile but crash.

I've read several things, but << assignment methods aren't getting through and I'm guessing it is something really simple.

Caveats:

1. I know people have written wrappers for this driver code in many other languages, but I would like to stick with this one if possible
2. I would like to keep it as OSC/UDP

Any guidance is appreciated